# Method doInBackground does not override from the superclass

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to use AsyncTask but both my doInBackground and onPostExecute methods give me the same error saying `Method does not override method from its superclass`. My code is:

```
public class SigninActivity extends AsyncTask{

    private TextView status, result;
    private Context context;
    private int flag = 0;

    public SigninActivity(Context context, TextView status, TextView result, int flag) {
        this.context = context;
        this.statusField = status;
        this.roleField = result;
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        //Code
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //Code
    }
```

Comment: You should check at the documentation of `AsyncTask` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask). I think your implementation is incorrect that's why it won't override methods.

Comment: `AsyncTask` takes three type paramters. You want `extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>` (also, the name of your class is confusing - it isn't an `Activity`, so best not to call it `SignInActivity`. `SignInTask` maybe?)

Comment: Because you did not specify the template arguments.

Comment: Please be aware of the fact that you should not name your class an "Activity" if it is not an Activity. This applies to any classes that are named in a some way, should be that thing that they are named.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create AsyncTask with three parameters < X,Y,Z >. For more details in [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)

```
    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // your code
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       //your code
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      //your code
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {
        // your code

    }
}
```